# Recycle view Adapter not updating value Getting BY Sqlite

Tags: android, database, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I have one application in which initially I am inserting parameter for font color and font size manually and by getting thoes data into adpater by reading database i was able to make change in fontsize and fontcolor of list items.

### Important code:

**insert method of helper:**

```
 public boolean insertData(ContactModel contactModel) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
//        contentValues.put(col_0,contactModel.getId());
        contentValues.put(col_1,contactModel.getName());
        contentValues.put(col_2,contactModel.getNumber());
        contentValues.put(col_3,contactModel.getColor());
        contentValues.put(col_4,contactModel.getFSize());
        contentValues.put(col_5,contactModel.getDataIndex());
//        long result =db.insert(Table_name,null,contentValues);

        long result = db.insertWithOnConflict(Table_name, null, contentValues,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);

        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**method for insert data :**

```
 public void tempinsert(String name,String num,String color,int size,int index){
        boolean inSamedata=tempSqliteDatabaseHelper.IsItemExist(name,num);
        if(inSamedata==false){
            boolean indata = tempSqliteDatabaseHelper.insertData(new ContactModel(name,num,color,size,index));
            if (indata == true) {
                Log.e("DataSave","DataSave");
            }
            else{
                Log.e("In_Data_not_True","In Data not True");
            }
        }else if(inSamedata==true){
            Log.e("Record_Exist","Record Exist");
        }
    }
```

**Calling above method:**

```
tempinsert(getDisplayName(),getPhNumber(),"#2d2d2d",35,1);
```

**As you can see I am inserting font color and size statically.**

**Code inside onBind method adapter for make change in list item:**

```
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyContactHolder myContactHolder, int i) {

        myContactHolder.Name.setText(customDataListModels.get(i).getName());
        myContactHolder.Number.setText(customDataListModels.get(i).getNumber());
        Log.e("poistionAdapter:", String.valueOf(myContactHolder.getPosition()));

        Cursor cursor = tempSqliteDatabaseHelper.getAllData();
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(mcontext.getApplicationContext(), "No Contact Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return;
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
           Integer SFontsize=cursor.getInt(4);
            String SColor=cursor.getString(3);
        myContactHolder.Name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(cursor.getString(3)));
            myContactHolder.Name.setTextSize(SFontsize);

            Log.d("Font_Size", String.valueOf(SFontsize));
            Log.d("Font_color", String.valueOf(SColor));
        }
    }
```

Here inside log I am getting same value as inserted, Everything is fine uptil this point, Problem occurs After i am updating fontsize and fontcolor in database.After update I am able get updated fontsize/color in log but whenever I am give thoes value to

```
myContactHolder.Name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(cursor.getString(3)));
                myContactHolder.Name.setTextSize(SFontsize);
```

Textview not updating it's font size and color according to update , Funny thing is for cursor.getString(3) and SFontsize ,, I am getting updating value.If u reqiued any other code for understand my problem post in comment.

Comment: Are you calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after updating the array?

Comment: yes I am , for make sure that i am also cheking after relauch app